# Creating horizonal line in html/css with a dot in center

Tags: html, css

how build a text with a separator like in photo? (line + dot + line).

how merge in css line and dot?

```css
.text{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
  clear: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 0px;
}

.text:before {
    content: "";
    background: #e85387;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text">Chi sono</p>
</div>
```

I have `:after` for line and `:before` for dot

[image]

But I view:

[image]

@Minal Chauhan with your edit i view this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backgrounds

```css
.text{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, red 90%,transparent ) bottom/ 10px 10px,
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) bottom 4px left  calc(50% - 50px)/ 70px 2px,
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) bottom 4px right calc(50% - 50px)/ 70px 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Chi sono</p>
```

With CSS variables to easily control:

```css
.text{
  --w:70px; /* line width */
  --h:2px;  /* line height */
  --c:10px; /* circle size */
  --d:10px; /* distance between line and circle */

  --y:calc((var(--c) - var(--h))/2);
  --x:calc(50% - var(--w)/2 - var(--d) - var(--c)/2);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, red 90%,transparent ) bottom / var(--c) var(--c),
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) bottom var(--y) left  var(--x) / var(--w) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) bottom var(--y) right var(--x) / var(--w) var(--h);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Chi sono</p>

<p class="text" style="--w:100px;--h:5px;--c:12px;">Chi sono</p>

<p class="text" style="--w:50px;--h:1px;--c:20px;--d:50px">Chi sono</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going right way, just add white border in `:before` selector

```css
.text{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
    
.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.text:before {
    content: "";
    background: #e85387;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 8px solid #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left: 8px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Latest Article</div>
```